# STL Vector of Unique_ptr - How to reset?

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, std, unique-ptr

I create two standard vector of unique_ptr:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Student>> students;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Teacher>> teachers;
```

Then, I create a new object and put it in the vector:

```
students.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Student> (new Student()));
teachers.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Teacher> (new Teacher()));
```

After all the operation I have to do, how can I delete the vector?

Whitout unique_ptr I had to do a loop and delete each object:

```
while (!students.empty())
{
    delete students.back();
    students.pop_back();
}
```

Now with unique_ptr what have I to do?

I know I have to use unique_ptr::reset (I think).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's simple:

```
students.clear();
```

That's what smart pointers (like `unique_ptr`) are for - they take care of destroying the object pointed to when appropriate.

Comment: So basically, when I call clear() all the object are deleted?

Comment: @user1860848 Yes, exactly. When you call `clear()`, the objects in the vector (the `unique_ptr`s) are deleted. When a `unique_ptr` is deleted, it deletes the object it's pointing to.

Comment: Is correct to write: std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Student *>> students; ? Just a curiosity.

Comment: @user1860848 Yes, but it means something totally different. It's a vector of unique-pointers to *dynamically allocated* raw-pointers to `Student`s. In such case, the raw-pointer pointed to would be deallocated when the unique-pointer is destroyed, but the `Student` instance would not be affected (and if it was dynamically allocated, it would probably be leaked).

Comment: @Angew why `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>>` does its job, while `std::vector<Object*>` does not? I believe that in the case of `unique_ptr`, the "deletes" are "performed" compile-time, while in the case of raw pointers it must be done dynamically. But what's the specific mechanism that makes C++ "know" the desired lifetime of the vector elements... that makes `vector.clear()` call destructors of non-pointer types?