# C++ data alignment of unique_ptr<> using _aligned_malloc()

Tags: c++, vector, malloc, unique-ptr, memory-alignment

I'm trying to make sure an object gets aligned before I add it to a `vector` data structure. Responding to a `warning C4316: 'Basic' : object allocated on the heap may not be aligned 16` warning, I have the following for the `Basic` object:

```
class Basic
{
public:
    Basic();
    ~Basic();
};
```

It's a standard object here. Next, a `unique_ptr` to a `new` instance of `Basic` is allocated for the benefits of doing so. (as opposed to a standard pointer)

```
unique_ptr<Basic> e_Basic{new Basic()};
```

And I attempted to align the data, so that I can avoid alignment issues later on:

```
e_Basic.reset =_aligned_malloc((size_t)sizeof(Basic), (size_t)(16 + (sizeof(Basic) % 16))); //Verify alignment.
```

Finally adding the pointer to the `vector` array.

```
LocalBasicQueue.push_back(move(e_Basic));
```

The compiler says that it is kosher, but my "What the fudge?" code sense is going off. Would this result in a pointer to (Surely) aligned code?

Is it ok to declare(`e_Basic.reset`) equal to a pointer [as returned by `_aligned_malloc()`] in this fashion and call its `unique_ptr<>`, having the new pointer assigned?

Comment: `e_Basic.reset = ...`? Unless you ask about compiler errors, please try to show correct code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Oh, and there's no need to cast the result of `sizeof ...`, it's automatically of type `size_t`. You should also try to avoid C-style casts in C++ as much as possible, and if possible casting in general. ***If*** you need to do a cast, try `static_cast` first.

Comment: I edited the post, thanks.

Comment: @RashidEllis `e_Basic.reset = x;` isn't something you can do. Do you mean `e_Basic.reset(x);`?

Comment: Yes, but @milesbudnek below states that, "You never initialize a Basic object in the memory allocated by _aligned_malloc". I'm trying to figure out what that implies for my implementation.

Comment: Read more about *placement new* as suggested in the answer. I.e. just allocate the correct amount of memory and assign it to a `void*` variable. Then do placement new using that pointer: `e_Basic.reset(new (the_pointer) Basic);` This will use the memory you allocated with `_aligned_malloc` for the object and *construct* the object (it's the construction step that you're missing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few problems with that code.

1. You allocate, construct, and then immediately destroy a `Basic` object for no reason.
2. You never initialize a `Basic` object in the memory allocated by `_aligned_malloc`.
3. By default `unique_ptr` will release the memory it manages with `delete`, but you didn't `new` that memory, you `_aligned_malloc`ed it.  This is a Bad Idea, and will likely result in heap corruption and/or crashes.

You can remedy the first problem simply by not initializing your `unique_ptr` with a `new Basic()`.

The second can be fixed using a placement new expression.

The third can be fixed by giving the `unique_ptr` a custom deleter that calls `~Basic` and `_aligned_free` instead of `delete`  Note though that a `unique_ptr<Basic, my_deleter>` is a different type than `unique_ptr<Basic>`, so you can't put that into a `vector<unique_ptr<Basic>>`.

The second and third problems can also be fixed by overloading `Basic::operator new` and `Basic::operator delete` to use `_aligned_malloc` and `_aligned_delete` respectively, but that will mean that `new Basic()` always uses `_aligned_malloc`, which you may or may not want.

Comment: It's still early and I can make that change without drastic implementation changes. Should I ignore the alignment warning and trust somehow that `unique_ptr<Basic>` points to aligned data in the vector?

Comment: No - you should take the advice given.

Comment: Thanks, for clarification, I want to make sure the pointer stored in `unique_ptr<Basic>` is aligned.

Comment: Ahh. Wait! I get it! Being that I [explicitly] malloc'ed the memory needed, it is now necessary to rewrite the deleter manually to accommodate the custom alignment specification. So, does this mean that I can set ownership of a unique_ptr to a custom aligned [standard] pointer?

Comment: If you allocate with `_aligned_malloc` you must free with `_aligned_free`.  It has nothing to do with the alignment, `new` just doesn't know about the memory at all, because it didn't allocate it for you.  The same would be true if you used regular `malloc`.

Comment: I also added a bit about overloading `operator new` and `operator delete` if you want all `Basic` objects to use `_aligned_malloc`.

Comment: Wrapping the noggin around that now... This is for a shader object, so I can store multiple shaders in a vector. But I got that warning and I haven't added anything major to the class.

Comment: I'm going to marked this as answer, since you show a clear solution based  on how the question was framed. Additionally I came across http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652432/stl-vector-of-unique-ptr-how-to-reset that "completed" how I was viewing `unique_ptr` Awesome guys, Thanks!